# Unit testing a parent class that uses Injector with Router (and other services)

Tags: angular, angular2-di

Suppose I have class `Foo` which provides dependency injected services to all its derived classes, as such:

```
export class Foo {
    protected fb : FormBuilder;
    protected router : Router;
    protected otherService : OtherService;
    protected anotherService : AnotherService;

    constructor(injector : Injector) {
        this.fb = injector.get(FormBuilder);
        this.router = injector.get(Router);
        this.otherService = injector.get(OtherService);
        this.anotherService = injector.get(AnotherService);
}
```

which has classes derived from it as such:

```
export class Bar extends Foo {

    constructor(injector : Injector){
         super(injector);
    }
}
```

How can I unit test the parent class correctly, without running into:

`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Foo: (?)`

At the minute I have (having tried many, *many* different things to get it to work, but failing :( )

```
export function main() {

    describe('Class: Foo', () => {
        beforeEach(async(() => {

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    Foo,
                    Injector,
                    OtherService,
                    AnotherService
                ]
            });
        }));


        it('should compile', inject([Foo, Injector], ( foo: Foo, injector : Injector ) => {
            console.log("INJECTOR", injector);
            expect(foo).toBeTruthy();
        }));

    });
}
```

I've also tried using `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate` as such:

```
{
    provide : Injector,
    useValue: ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([FormBuilder, Router, OtherService, AnotherService])
}
```

But still no dice :( Any ideas?

Comment: `Injector : injector` is it typo? I suspect you want to write `injector : Injector`

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.... updated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you need to add `@Inject` decorator for `Injector` in `Foo` constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(Injector) injector: Injector) {
```

and configure `TestBed` properly. More precisely you have to import `RouterModule` otherwise you will get another issue with `Router`:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [    
    FormBuilder,
    Foo,
    OtherService,
    AnotherService
  ]
});
```

You can try it in action in **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pH0TKTjhGqPuqmDa7wrt?p=preview)**

Comment: That seems to have solved it! Interestingly enough, the code itself worked perfectly fine without the `@Inject` decorator, just not in the unit tests!